# Count total number of pages in .TIF file in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to get Python to read exactly how many pages are in a .TIF and I've modified some code from some help I got yesterday. I've gotten Python to read the .TIF file, and output the pages, however it only reads the first .TIF file it can find. I need it to go through all the .TIF files in the same location.

I was wondering how can I make it so that once it is done counting, it will continue to the next file until it is completely done.

Here is what I have so far

```
import os
from PIL import Image

count = 0
i = 0
tiffs_path = "c:\\tiftest"

for filename in os.listdir("c:\\tiftest"):
    if filename.endswith(".TIF"):
        img = Image.open(filename)
        while True:
            try:   
                img.seek(count)
                print(filename)
                print(count)
            except EOFError:
                break       
            count += 1          

print(count)
```

Comment: Surprised this works at all because you're not reading the files from the same directory you got the listing from.

Comment: Move `count = 0` after `Image.open(...`

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Image.n_frames` to find the number of frames in a TIFF. It was added in Pillow 2.9.0.

For example, with Pillow 4.2.1:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 18 2016, 07:03:39)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> img = Image.open("multipage.tiff")
>>> img.n_frames
3
>>>
```

So, something like this:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

count = 0
i = 0
tiffs_path = "c:\\tiftest"

for filename in os.listdir("c:\\tiftest"):
    if filename.endswith(".TIF"):
        img = Image.open(filename)
        print(filename)
        print(img.n_frames)
```