# How to count page of this file in python or java exactly?

Tags: java, python

[03512378.tif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/102tRrLJtlZFo7B3yrMfD-03-pO4aqRUX/view?usp=drivesdk)

** The original extension of the attached tif file is img. **

Linked Img file is multi-pages Image.
Total page of this file is 178 in window picture viewer.
But The total page is 350 In Imagick(Image handling program), JAI(java module) and PIL python package.

```
## my python code ##
import os
from PIL import Image
count = 0
i = 0
tiffs_path = "l:/fun"
for filename in os.listdir("l:/fun"):
    if filename.endswith(".tif"):
        img = Image.open(filename)
        while True:
            try:   
                img.seek(count)                
            except EOFError:
                break       
            count += 1          
        print(filename+"::"+str(count))
```

I want count page of file like the above exactly.
(Total page of this file is 178.)

How to count page of this file in python or java?
(There seems to be an my unknown attribute in the linked img file-03512378.tif-.)

Comment: Check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458103/count-total-number-of-pages-in-tif-file-in-python

Comment: Total page is 350 using code of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458103/count-total-number-of-pages-in-tif-file-in-python. It is similar my python code. I want to get result value(178). ^^;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is a little tricky to solve. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF),

> There may be more than one Image File Directory (IFD) in a TIFF file. Each IFD defines a subfile. One use of subfiles is to describe related images, such as the pages of a facsimile document.

Essentially, this means that you may have frames holding only (meta) information, and not any actual image. I tried studying the meta data of your specific TIFF-file, and quickly realized that there was duplication in the **ImageDescription**, hinting about frames belonging to the same image. The code I've written below prints,

`PIL reports '350' frames`

`Number of unique frames : 177`

`Number of counted frames: 350`

I got quite close, though not spot on, as my OS's image veiwer reports 178 images; same as you do. Still, this might be of some help to you: You may for instance continue investigating the meta data by printing the dict `meta`. Also, beware that this approach assumes all of your TIFF-files to have their meta data structured similarily.

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL.TiffTags import TAGS

im = Image.open("03512378.tif")
print("PIL reports '"+ str(im.n_frames) +"' frames")

count = 1
img_numbers = []
while True:
    try:
        im.seek(im.tell()+1)
        meta = {TAGS[key] : im.tag[key] for key in im.tag.keys()}
        img_numbers.append((meta["ImageDescription"][0]))
        # Note: elements in the meta dict are tuples
    except EOFError:
        break
    count += 1

s = set(img_numbers) # remove duplicates
print("Number of unique frames : " + str(len(s)))
print("Number of counted frames: " + str(count))
```